# Firebase-tools update failing or just reporting wrong version?

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I'm trying to update firebase-tools using npm to the latest version (6.7.1). `firebase -V` keeps reporting the old version (6.4.0) but I am not sure if it's been updated or not. This is in Ubuntu linux

Here is what I did in the terminal

```
hili@dev:~$ npm list -g | grep fireb
└─┬ firebase-tools@6.4.0
  ├─┬ firebase@2.4.2
hili@dev:~$ sudo npm update -g firebase-tools
[sudo] password for hili: 
/usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
+ firebase-tools@6.7.1
updated 1 package in 15.73s
hili@dev:~$ npm list -g | grep fireb
└─┬ firebase-tools@6.4.0
  ├─┬ firebase@2.4.2
```

Note that after the update, it does report the new version but then when i list, it still shows the old one.
I tried debugging the script in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js` and I see this

```
var pkg = require("../../package.json");
...
logger.debug("CLI Version:  ", pkg.version);
```

So I check in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/package.json` and I see this. It seems to be a mix of the old and the new version

```
{
  "_from": "firebase-tools@6.7.1",
  "_id": "firebase-tools@6.7.1",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-8JZ2QA1gylgmlGNULrhTtkk5iS+OumCoJEgK+RNLt/ji1hSxzZehWCb13jHtqCRNRz+Kt+uwsrmExbhsNNqiBw==",
  "_location": "/firebase-tools",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "version",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "firebase-tools@6.7.1",
    "name": "firebase-tools",
    "escapedName": "firebase-tools",
    "rawSpec": "6.7.1",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "6.7.1"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools/-/firebase-tools-6.7.1.tgz",
  "_shasum": "c80ddc9cfd6ca6611b50e3e656f8bee30621c6f3",
  "_spec": "firebase-tools@6.7.1",
  "_where": "/home/hili",
  "author": {
    "name": "Firebase",
    "url": "https://firebase.google.com/"
  },
  "bin": {
    "firebase": "./lib/bin/firebase.js"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-emulator": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "JSONStream": "^1.2.1",
    "archiver": "^2.1.1",
    "cjson": "^0.3.1",
    "cli-color": "^1.2.0",
    "cli-table": "^0.3.1",
    "commander": "^2.8.1",
    "configstore": "^1.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "cross-spawn": "^4.0.0",
    "csv-streamify": "^3.0.4",
    "didyoumean": "^1.2.1",
    "es6-set": "^0.1.4",
    "exit-code": "^1.0.2",
    "filesize": "^3.1.3",
    "firebase": "2.x.x",
    "fs-extra": "^0.23.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "google-auto-auth": "^0.7.2",
    "inquirer": "^0.12.0",
    "is": "^3.2.1",
    "jsonschema": "^1.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "opn": "^5.3.0",
    "ora": "0.2.3",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "progress": "^2.0.0",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "semver": "^5.0.3",
    "superstatic": "^6.0.1",
    "tar": "^4.3.0",
    "tmp": "0.0.33",
    "universal-analytics": "^0.4.16",
    "update-notifier": "^2.5.0",
    "user-home": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.0",
    "winston": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "Command-Line Interface for Firebase",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/cli-color": "^0.3.29",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/glob": "^7.1.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.118",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/nock": "^9.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.0",
    "@types/opn": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.1",
    "@types/sinon": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.6",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mocha": "^5.0.5",
    "nock": "^9.3.3",
    "nyc": "^13.3.0",
    "prettier": "1.14.3",
    "sinon": "^6.3.4",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.2.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.9",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-no-unused-expression-chai": "^0.1.4",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "engineStrict": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "templates"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools",
  "keywords": [
    "cdn",
    "cli",
    "ssl",
    "cloud",
    "hosting",
    "firebase",
    "realtime",
    "websockets",
    "synchronization"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "name": "firebase-tools",
  "nyc": {
    "require": [
      "ts-node/register"
    ],
    "extension": [
      ".js",
      ".ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "src/test/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-emulator": "^1.0.0-beta.5"
  },
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "clean": "rm -rf lib",
    "format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.{js,ts}'",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:ts",
    "lint:js": "eslint 'src/**/*.js'",
    "lint:ts": "tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json",
    "mocha": "nyc mocha --opts mocha.opts",
    "prepare": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "prepublish": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run mocha"
  },
  "version": "6.4.0"
}
```

At the beginning I see references to firebase-tools@6.7.1 but in the last line of the file I do have `"version": "6.4.0"`
What version is actually installed? and more importantly, how can I fix this so that i have 6.7.1 installed *and* reported in `firebase -V`

Comment: The packages you install locally (in the project's package.json) can be different than the ones you install globally with -g.  Make sure you're actually updating firebase-tools globally, and make sure your PATH is referring to the correct one.

Comment: @DougStevenson you can see in my question that I always used `-g` in my commands so everything should be global. The `package.json` file is also in a global location for the system: `/usr/local/lib`